# Can I replace my gas water heater control valve with one from a different manufacturer?

Tags: water-heater, gas

Can I replace the Honeywell gas water heater control valve (model number WT8840B1500) with a Reliance control valve?

Comment: Does the Reliance valve (knowing the model number might help) state that it's a replacement part for the Honeywell valve? If so, you have the mfgr's assurance that you can. If not, you'll need to know a lot of details (like size & gender of fittings, gas flow rates, etc) for both valves to ensure one is a suitable replacement for the other.